# bluetooth messed up by kernel 3.13-46

Tags: bluetooth

since the last kernel update bluetooth is broken,
which was working fine before.

main message in syslog is "DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled"

it looks like an acpi problem to me, but would need some hints
how to get stuff back to run.

Machine is a ZOTAC EN760 which was running fine with the last kernel
revisions until yesterday, but going back to 3.13-45 didnt seem to help, 
are modules messed up by kernel updates?

Any help would be appreciated.

data updates by request:

```
carsten@carsten-ZBOX-EN760:~$ sudo dkms autoinstall
[sudo] password for carsten: 


carsten@carsten-ZBOX-EN760:~$ lsusb; dmesg | grep -i firmware -    
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0480:a200 Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0812  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader     Controller
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:0719 Microsoft Corp. Xbox 360 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 152e:2571 LG (HLDS) 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:2812  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0457:1057 Silicon Integrated Systems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.171228] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.435664] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

Working device will list:

```
carsten@carsten-ZBOX-EN760:~$ lsusb; dmesg | grep -i firmware -
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0480:a200 Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0812  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:0719 Microsoft Corp. Xbox 360 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 152e:2571 LG (HLDS) 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:2812  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0457:1057 Silicon Integrated Systems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.142375] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.423106] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.082644] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
[    2.202206] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
```

Comment: What's the output of `sudo dkms autoinstall`?

Comment: no output given by that command, but also no error message

Comment: Can you add to your question the results from terminal of `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Comment: Any result from `hciconfig -a`

Comment: "hciconfig -a" gives zero output,
"hciconfig scan" tells me no such device

Comment: Does `lsmod | grep btusb` have any results?  A kernel update shouldn't mess things up for an older kernel as each kernel has its own modules

Comment: no btusb is not automatically loaded,
loading it manually also doesnt change the situation

Comment: If it is a bluetooth device that is part of the wifi card, it is showing any sign of working

Comment: Yes it is the bluetooth device which is together with the wifi module from intel, the wireless lan still works though, just tested it right now.
I contacted the Service and will get a replacement part in the next days.

Comment: replacement arrived, bluetooth is found again, thanks all for the help, ubuntu was not at fault.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's problem was caused by a hardware fault. That is stated in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the uuids with

```
sudo update-usbids
```

then you will see the correct names for the device. If not sure use

```
watch -d lsusb
```

and plug in and out the device to find out which is the correct one.

Then google for the id of the device, for example "2109:0812" and get the correct driver